# Update Table Contents With Value From The Same Table

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with 10000 rows

product_id | price | price_inc_vat | vat_rate

I want to be able to update the value of price_inc_vat based on the value of price

I have tried this

```
UPDATE 1_products AS s3, 
       1_products AS t3

SET    t3.price_inc = ROUND(s3.price*1.3,2)

WHERE  s3.vat_rate = 20 AND t3.vat_rate=20;
```

It doesn't error but seems to be taking a very long time as I had to kill the query after 1/2 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a field for `price` and another for `price_inc_vat` and yet another for `vat_rate`? Why not just store `price` and `vat_rate` and calculate `price_inc_vat` when it's needed?

Also, why are you multiplying by 1.3 when the VAT you're targeting appears to be 20%?

All these logical inconsistencies aside, couldn't you just do the following?

```
UPDATE products
SET price_inc_vat = ROUND(price * 1.3, 2)
WHERE vat_rate = 20
```

Or to update everything after a VAT change, disregarding the 10% markup:

```
UPDATE products
SET price_inc_vat = ROUND(price * (1+vat_rate/100), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why the join?

```
UPDATE products SET price_inc_vat = ROUND(price*1.3,2) WHERE vat_rate=20;
```

**UPDATED**
I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve by updating a product's "Inc. price" with another products price, but the reason that your query is taking so long is because of the way that you are joining.

```
mysql> create table t1 (product_id integer unsigned primary key, price decimal(10,2), price_inc_vat decimal(10,2), vat_rate integer unsigned);

mysql> insert into t1 values (1, 1.00, 1.20, 20), (2, 2.00, 2.40, 20), (3, 1.00, 1.30, 30);

mysql> select * from (t1 as s3, t1 as t3) where s3.vat_rate=20 and t3.vat_rate=20;
1   1.00    1.20    20  1   1.00    1.20    20
2   2.00    2.40    20  1   1.00    1.20    20
1   1.00    1.20    20  2   2.00    2.40    20
2   2.00    2.40    20  2   2.00    2.40    20

mysql> select s3.*, t3.*, round(s3.price * 1.3, 2) from (t1 as s3, t1 as t3) where s3.vat_rate=20 and t3.vat_rate=20;
1   1.00    1.20    20  1   1.00    1.20    20  1.30
2   2.00    2.40    20  1   1.00    1.20    20  2.60
1   1.00    1.20    20  2   2.00    2.40    20  1.30
2   2.00    2.40    20  2   2.00    2.40    20  2.60

mysql> update (t1 as s3, t1 as t3) set t3.price_inc_vat=round(s3.price*1.3, 2) where s3.vat_rate=20 and t3.vat_rate=20;

mysql> select * from (t1 as s3, t1 as t3) where s3.vat_rate=20 and t3.vat_rate=20;
1   1.00    1.30    20  1   1.00    1.30    20
2   2.00    1.30    20  1   1.00    1.30    20
1   1.00    1.30    20  2   2.00    1.30    20
2   2.00    1.30    20  2   2.00    1.30    20
```

If you are trying to set product prices based upon a previous price set then perhaps the following will help clarify things:

```
mysql> create table t1 (
  product_id integer unsigned, 
  vat_rate integer unsigned, 
  price decimal(10,2), 
  price_inc_vat decimal(10,2), 
  primary key(product_id, vat_rate)
);

mysql> insert into t1 (product_id, price, price_inc_vat, vat_rate) values (1, 1.00, 1.20, 20), (2, 2.00, 2.40, 20), (1, 1.00, 0, 30), (2, 2.00, 0, 30);

mysql> create temporary table tmp1 like t1;

mysql> insert into tmp1 select * from t1;

mysql> select * from t1;
1       20      1.00    1.20
1       30      1.00    0.00
2       20      2.00    2.40
2       30      2.00    0.00

mysql> select * from tmp1;
1       20      1.00    1.20
1       30      1.00    0.00
2       20      2.00    2.40
2       30      2.00    0.00

mysql> update t1 left join tmp1 on t1.product_id=tmp1.product_id and t1.vat_rate > tmp1.vat_rate set t1.price_inc_vat = round(tmp1.price*(1+t1.vat_rate/100), 2) where tmp1.vat_rate = 20;

mysql> select * from t1;
1       20      1.00    1.20
1       30      1.00    1.30
2       20      2.00    2.40
2       30      2.00    2.60
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I used the code to update rows based on values in different rows on the same table but for the large table the rows are the same.

Comment: i cannot believe that you really want to join the table with itself for that update. look at the shortend table result and please tell again if this is your expected result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70531/2/0

Comment: @SirRufo Was your comment aimed StephenBouffe or me?

Comment: @Cez no, it was aimed to Stephen